# Given the connectivity of $A$ and $A\wedge B$, what can be said about the connectivity of $B$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $A$ and $B$ be well pointed CW-complexes. I guess an answer to the question in the title is, that nothing can be said about the connectivity of $B$. Therefore, I ask for a counter example:

> Given any $n\geq 0$, what is an example of $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is $n$-connected and $A\wedge B$ is $n$-connected but $B$ is **not** $n$-connecetd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $A = S^{n+1}$, so that $S^{n+1} \wedge B = \Sigma^{n+1} B$ is the $(n+1)$-fold suspension. If $B$ is connected, then the first $n$ homology groups of $\Sigma^{n+1} B$ vanish and the fundamental group of $\Sigma^{n+1} B$ is trivial, so by repeated application of the Hurewicz theorem it follows that $\Sigma^{n+1} B$ is $n$-connected. But $B$ need not be $n$-connected, just connected.

This answers the question for $n \ge 1$. For $n = 0$ take $A = S^1, B = S^0$.

Answer (score 0):

I think if $A$ is $(n-1)$-connected and $B$ is $(m-1)$-connected then $A\wedge B$ is $(n + m- 1)$-connected.